Getting NameError for pandas dataframe
I have df1 with column 'col' & df2 with columns 'code' and 'id'. Column 'col' in df1 is mapped to 'code' column in df2. When I am running the below code:
def get_id_for_code(code):
    try:
        return df2.loc[df2['code'] == code, 'id'].iloc[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result['resultId'] = get_id_for_code(row['col'])

The error is thrown as:
return df2.loc[df2['code'] == code, 'id'].iloc[0]
NameError: name 'df2' is not defined

Can someone please help with resolving this issue.
Note: The dataframes are generated dynamically. They are huge and internal to the company. A sample of the dataframe:
Sample DataFrames
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'code': ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4']
})
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'project': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
})

Thanks in advance.

Ic correct df1 in sample data? It should be df and column code filled codes starting A,B, C... ?

The code you provided uses variable df and result, but in the sample you presented, neither df nor result exists. We can't answer questions that aren't reproducible, so please improve your question.

Thanks for your reply.
I am able fix it by passing the dataframe 'df2' as a parameter to the function.
def get_id_for_code(code, df2):
    try:
        return df2.loc[df2['code'] == code, 'id'].iloc[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result['resultId'] = get_id_for_code(row['col'], df2)


Here loops are not necessary, use Series.map and for select first id per codes DataFrame.drop_duplicates with DataFrame.set_index
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'code': ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4']
})
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5']
})

df['resultId'] = df['col'].map(df2.drop_duplicates('code').set_index('code')['id'])
print (df)
  col  resultId
0  A1       1.0
1  B2       2.0
2  C3       3.0
3  D4       4.0
4  E5       NaN

Or for first values per codes (with omit NaNs) use GroupBy.first:
df['resultId'] = df['col'].map(df2.groupby('code')['id'].first())

Your solution is possible change by assign value, but not recommended, because really slow:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'resultId'] = get_id_for_code(row['col'])

Also error:

NameError: name 'df2' is not defined

means there is no DataFrame called df2.

Thanks for your reply. I understand that loops are not necessary, but since we doing other computations on the dataframe, that's why I am using loop.

@Pallavi - added solution, but best not use it.
